# Moment.js How to convert MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff to round-trip date/time pattern?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-format

How can I transform the string `"8/3/2017 6:12:00 AM"` to `"2017-08-03T06:12:00.000"` by using standard JavaScript or `moment.js` library?

Comment: Actually you can look at here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can convert `8/3/2017 6:12:00 AM` to `2017-08-03T06:12:00.000` using moment the following way:

```
moment("8/3/2017 6:12:00 AM", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss a').format('YYYY-DD-MMTHH:mm:ss.000')
```

```js
console.log(moment("8/3/2017 6:12:00 AM", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss a').format('YYYY-DD-MMTHH:mm:ss.000'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no need to hardcode `000` milliseconds in the format string, moment has the uppercase `SSS` token for [Fractional Second](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 0):

if you know what format you are getting then i suggest to parse and create an js date object. and then

```js
var year = 2017;
var month = 2;
var day = 8;
var date = new Date(year, month, day);
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

**Updated:**

```js
console.log(moment("8/3/2017 6:12:00 AM", 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss a').format('YYYY-DD-MMTHH:mm:ss.000'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```