# Why react-datepicker is not selecting correct date?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm newbie in React and I have used [this datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) and used following code

```
    class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Definition of handlechange is given below

```
handleChange(date) {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
    }
```

After this I have converted that date in format which I need in my program

```
var dateformat = (new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',
            { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit', 
hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' }).format(this.state.startDate));
```

Sometimes it selects correct date. But most of the time it's returning this **01-01-0001 12:00:00 AM** date & time which is default.

Due to that date, Exception which I usually gets is given below:

> "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be
>   between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan value)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime value)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime..ctor(DateTime value)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.FromDateTime(DateTime dateTime, Byte
>   cb)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.WriteUnterminatedValue(Object value,
>   MetaType type, Byte scale, Int32 actualLength, Int32 encodingByteSize,
>   Int32 offset, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Int32 paramSize, Boolean
>   isDataFeed)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray,
>   Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest
>   notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean
>   isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32
>   startRpc, Int32 startParam)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean
>   asyncWrite, String method)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2
>   parameterValues)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection
>   connection)"

Can anyone help me in understanding where am I making mistake? Is there any bug in that react-datepicker? Please give me solution for this problem.

Comment: You can use `moment.js` to format your date - https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have used moment.js and used like this - moment(this.state.startDate,'DD/MM/YYYY').format() - its returning current time also. How can I get only date?

Comment: moment(this.state.startDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');  this will give you date only.

Comment: No its returning time also. Do I need to make changes in settings of react-datepicker?

Comment: No. it should not return time. check this - https://jsbin.com/latafefehi/edit?html,js,console

Comment: You have used default date() function from JavaScript. Please use [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) and check results.

Comment: I have provided a demo in my answer. check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format a `date`, [`moment`](https://momentjs.com/) is a good option.

```
moment(this.state.startDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-vpiiv?fontsize=14)

Comment: After debugging I came across, it happened because of data type that I have used. DateTime data type of C# is automatically taking default time 12:00:00 AM. I've tried Date variable for extracting only date but it's not working. Do you have solution for that?

Comment: you can check the string + Format section from moment docs. You need something like this, moment(this.state.startDate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS').format('DD/MM/YYY').

Answer (score -1):

First convert `date` to `localestring` like below:

For example Date picker value will be like **Sun July 12 2020**

```
var date = date.toLocaleString()
```

Output will be like:

> 07/12/2020, 12.00 am

then use formatting in moment like below:

((dateoutputabove).replace(/,/g,''MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss").format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss")

will give you the right result in picker.
Also refer [Moment.js How to convert MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff to round-trip date/time pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567255/moment-js-how-to-convert-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-fff-to-round-trip-date-time-pattern/45567535#45567535)